# Visual Studio 2019 crashes while opening JavaScript file

Tags: visual-studio-2019

My Visual Studio can not open JS files

```
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
No exports were found that match the constraint: 
ContractName    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ToolsOptions.FileContentTypeService
RequiredTypeIdentity    Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ToolsOptions.FileContentTypeService
```

Any recipies with ComponentCache not working,
also log

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.Features.Formatting.TypeScriptEditorFormattingService.ctor(formattingHandler): expected exactly 1 export matching constraints:
Contract name: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.Features.Formatting.FormattingHandler
TypeIdentityName: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.Features.Formatting.FormattingHandler
but found 0.
part definition Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.Features.Formatting.TypeScriptEditorFormattingService

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExternalAccess.VSTypeScript.VSTypeScriptEditorInlineRenameService.ctor(service): expected exactly 1 export matching constraints:
Contract name: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExternalAccess.VSTypeScript.Api.IVSTypeScriptEditorInlineRenameService
TypeIdentityName: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExternalAccess.VSTypeScript.Api.IVSTypeScriptEditorInlineRenameService
but found 0.
part definition Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExternalAccess.VSTypeScript.VSTypeScriptEditorInlineRenameService

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExternalAccess.VSTypeScript.VSTypeScriptBreakpointResolutionService.ctor(implementation): expected exactly 1 export matching constraints:
Contract name: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExternalAccess.VSTypeScript.Api.IVSTypeScriptBreakpointResolutionServiceImplementation
TypeIdentityName: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExternalAccess.VSTypeScript.Api.IVSTypeScriptBreakpointResolutionServiceImplementation
but found 0.
part definition Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExternalAccess.VSTypeScript.VSTypeScriptBreakpointResolutionService

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExternalAccess.VSTypeScript.VSTypeScriptLanguageDebugInfoService.ctor(implementation): expected exactly 1 export matching constraints:
Contract name: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExternalAccess.VSTypeScript.Api.IVSTypeScriptLanguageDebugInfoServiceImplementation
TypeIdentityName: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExternalAccess.VSTypeScript.Api.IVSTypeScriptLanguageDebugInfoServiceImplementation
but found 0.
part definition Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ExternalAccess.VSTypeScript.VSTypeScriptLanguageDebugInfoService

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.Features.Formatting.TypeScriptFormattingService.ctor(formattingHandler): expected exactly 1 export matching constraints:
Contract name: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.Features.Formatting.FormattingHandler
TypeIdentityName: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.Features.Formatting.FormattingHandler
but found 0.
part definition Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.Features.Formatting.TypeScriptFormattingService

[image]

Comment: try to [repair Visual studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @magicandre1981  My studio working fine. It can not open just only ONE file type - JavaScript. What exactly going wrong with JS - ?

Comment: I have no idea. try to repair it

Comment: is it fixed after a repair?

Comment: Same problem. Suddenly VS2019 can't open js files from an MVC core 3.1 solution. I'll post back if I can convincingly resolve the problem.

Comment: I have also had this problem. It has only just come on and persisted after updating to the latest version. It actually became worse after this - it will not open js files at all.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the following folder and restart Visual studio.

```
C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0\ComponentModelCache
```